# Most difficult word to pronounce

Tags: pronunciation

This question is mainly for all those that are not speaking English as their first language.

For me there has been some words that are difficult to pronounce correctly. Maybe saying word aloud gives you a feeling that you're doing something wrong.

It would be interesting to know which words you find difficult?

My favourites are *squirrel*, *miscellaneous* (plus I have to always check how is this written correctly) and murderer (it's mumbling when I say it)

Comment: Maybe this belongs on community-wiki?

Comment: Try _pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis_ :D

Comment: I would rather say that this belongs closed, as *every* word is potentially difficult to pronounce correctly, depending on what one's mother tongue is.

Comment: but that is the interesting part of the question - what different speakers find hard.

Comment: @mplungjan: I'm not saying that the question is not *interesting to me*, I'm only saying that it might be considered too broad, too localized, subjective and argumentative, and *off-topic for the site*.

Comment: I understand RedDwight's point, but I don't understand how this is off-top for site that has a title English Language & Usage?

Comment: I have to consciously recall the pronunciation of the word 'concatenation' to stop myself stumbling over the word if reading aloud.

Answer (score 2):

Mine are refrigerator and budgerigar (I am Danish) I have no problems at all with your words :)

Do you know if your issues have to do with you being Finnish, would other Finns have the same problem?

Comment: ["Danish so-called 'pronunciation'"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/28/46208.aspx). (^_^)

Comment: I luckily do NOT have a Danish accent. Dey ar vari rekoknaisabel ven dey spik ainglis...

Comment: Good question. I haven't discussed with other Finns about this, but it seems that squirrel is "favourite" for many..

Comment: Just called a Finnish colleague. He had zero problems with the words you mentioned. But he also told me there would be no words beginning with skw in Finnish :)

Answer (score 1):

Many Frenchmen have problems with some phonemes that you do not find in French: `/ð/` and `/þ/` (*th*is and mou*th*).

Reciprocically, many native English speakers may face difficulties with the `/y/` (ü in German, u in French).

Answer (score 0):

Well, and what about:

> supercalifragilisticexpialidocious

Comment: Piece of cake ;) Like onomatopoetic

Comment: Yikes, that's difficult one